# When clicking a file to create a jstree leaf, it create many leafs using jquery

Tags: jquery

How can ensure the click event only clicks one time and not many times that creates multiple leaf nodes in jstree? Code below sometimes create multiple leaf nodes when clicking the file button

Here is the code:

```
        $(".hoverTree").hover(function()
        {
              $(this).on("click", function(event)
              {
                   if($.trim($(this).attr("value")) == "fileButton")
                   {
                       var fileID = setID();
                       $("#treeFile").jstree("create", null, "last", {"attr" : "SpecialFile", "id" : "file_"+fileID})
                   }
              });
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.one()`

```
$(this).one("click", function(event)
          {
               if($.trim($(this).attr("value")) == "fileButton")
               {
                   var fileID = setID();
                   $("#treeFile").jstree("create", null, "last", {"attr" : "SpecialFile", "id" : "file_"+fileID})
               }
          });
```

Comment: Do it again? You would have to leave the tree with the mouse and come back in so the `one` rebinds the click event.